# Attach one gameobject to another when they collide

Tags: c#, android, mobile, unity-game-engine

So i have 2 gameobjects Player and Puck.
Whenever player touches(collides)  the puck i want the puck to attach to player. 
So far i can get the puck to teleport to player but i dont want that. 
I want puck to attach to empty gameobject sloth i have placed in my player as a child.

**`Here's my code`**

```
public class CollisionDetector : MonoBehaviour {

     GameObject empty; //declare empty GameObject called "empty"

     Vector3 pos; //declare empty Vector3

    GameObject player;

    public bool collided;


    void Start() { 
        empty = GameObject.Find("holdSlot"); //Appends actual gameobject called "Empty" to our 'empty' variable we recently declared
        player = GameObject.Find("Player"); //Appends actual gameobject called "Player" to our 'player' variable we recently declared
        collided = false;
        pos = empty.transform.position; //ettii holdSlotin paikan ja laittaa sen "pos" nimelle

    }


   void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) { 

        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            //Do something on collide
            //transform.position = pos;
            collided = true;
        }
    }

    void Update() { 

        if (collided == true)
        {
            transform.position = pos;
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: You can't attach a GameOjbect to another GameObject. You attach scripts to GameObjects. What do you mean by attach?

Comment: Can't you simply make your object a child of `empty` on collision and set local position to `Vector3.zero`?

Comment: I making a hockey game. So i want my puck to attach my player when player touches it..

Comment: @Hellium Yeah , idk maybe i could just dont know how :D Im still a newb but really want to make this game work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make the puck a child of the player, that way it will follow them around.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        transform.SetParent(col.gameObject.transform, true);
    }
}
```

The `true` value on parameter `worldPositionStays` makes sure that the pucks current world position is kept, while its parent is changed to the player object.

Alternatively, if you want the puck to jump to a default position, for example right in front of the player, you can do:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        transform.SetParent(col.gameObject.transform, false);
        transform.localPosition = SomeDefaultPositionInPlayersLocalSpace;
    }
}
```

Notice that both solutions don't require you to update the puck's position during Update.

Once you want to shoot the puck, thus detaching it from the player, simply do `transform.SetParent(null, true);` and then move it around freely.

Comment: okay, i did as u said and used the exact script piece u wrote. Still puck does not move when player touches it. IDK what is wrong, or what i am doing wrong. Player object is tagged as a "Player" and both puck and player has collider components on them.. Puck does not have a rigidbody tough but should not cause the problem here.. Also attached the script on my "Player" object. and cleared the update method.

Comment: Have you removed what you do in your update while testing this?

Comment: yeah only got this in a script attached to "puck"  void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        transform.SetParent(col.gameObject.transform, true);
    }
}

Comment: Could it be because my player and puck has "Box collider 2D" on them and the player object also the Puck object are both 3D models?

Comment: @ToniHenriksson You should not be using a `BoxCollider2D` on 3D models. Replace it by a regular `BoxCollider`.

Comment: The key to troubleshooting is to devide the problem and conquer each of the subproblems individually. First, make sure OnCollisionEnter is called, by adding `Debug.Log` output. If not, solve that problem first, then proceed from there.

Comment: Hey Guys! Thank you all for the help. It was infact that Rigidbody2D and Box Collider 2D that was causing the problem. Works perfect now that those two have been swapped to regular boxcollider/rigidbody.